# Translucent tab bar in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: ios7, sencha-touch-2

I was wondering what is the best way to make the tab bar translucent (iOS7 style) and have the content scroll underneath it. I am using a tab panel. Thoughts?

I tried setting tab bar to floating:true, but:
1. tabBar seems to be intended for private use and couldn't find floating property on it
2. On doing the following on the tab panel:

```
tabBar: {            
    floating: true
},
tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
```

I'm just getting the tab bar to be docked on top. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, you can't achieve translucence with CSS and dynamic content underneath.  If it was a static image, you could do it.

You can approximate the effect with transparency.  You basically need to use a container as your tab bar and style it with "position: absolute;" and set bottom: 0.  The tab bar container shouldn't be an item of the list, rather an item of a container which also has the list.

Here's a quick example:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/26i

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

        var toolbar = {
            xtype: 'container',
            bottom: 0,
            alias: 'bottomtoolbar',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [

                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Option 1',
                    style: 'background: transparent;',
                    iconAlign: 'top',
                    width: 80,
                    height: 60,
                    margin: '0 10 0 10'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Option 2',
                    style: 'background: transparent;',
                    iconAlign: 'top',
                    width: 80,
                    height: 60,
                    margin: '0 10 0 10'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Option 3',
                    style: 'background: transparent;',
                    iconAlign: 'top',
                    width: 80,
                    height: 60,
                    margin: '0 10 0 10'
                }
            ],
            width: '100%',
            height: 80,
            style: 'position: absolute; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);'
        };

        var list = {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{title}',
            items: [
                {
                    // Spacer so end of list is selectable
                    xtype: 'container',
                    height: 80,
                    scrollDock: 'bottom'
                }
            ],
            data: [
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 4' }
            ]
        };

        Ext.Viewport.add(toolbar);
        Ext.Viewport.add(list);
    }
});
```

Granted, it's not styled very well, but you get the idea.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tabbar is docked by default to the bottom of the screen so even if you make it translucent all the content will be above it you will be unable to achieve what you wish. Instead you can set a bottom for the tab bar to position it below then add some opacity like .75 or .8 to try & get what you want